# Dynamic Discovery Docker Compose

Tags: docker, dynamic, docker-compose

I am using docker compose to bring up and dynamically scale a database.The containers all live within the same network, and there are a few different images that run, some which can scale and some which cant. Is there a way from within the other dockers to "see" all containers of type "x" on a certain network, so that I can load balance/etc effectively between them?

Comment: In most plain-Docker implementations of this, I've generally seen the same technologies used that you'd use without Docker (for example, Kafka relies on ZooKeeper here).  Kubernetes's Service abstraction provides another means of discovery but you'd have to specifically build your application to know about it.

Comment: A very generic "can container X do Y to other containers in plain Docker" answer is "not without being given unrestricted root-level access over the entire host, and you usually don't want that".  This includes both tasks like starting and stopping containers and what you'd otherwise expect to be "read-only" tasks like listing them.

Comment: Ah David again on my Qs! I think I should just pay for a half hour of your time. Yes I had worried that K8 was the way to go really, I have only just learned docker for the first time so hoped docker-compose would give an out the box/canonical solution for this sort of thing

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to know their names, you can use the docker DNS resolver to discover them. This is actually likely to be the thing you want to do with a load balancer anyway. Think of Nginx upstream directive, or HAProxy backends.

```yaml
services:
  app:
    image: nginx
    deploy:
      replicas: 2

networks:
  default:
    name: sample
```

If you deploy this, you can query the docker DNS resolver from the same network to ask for the IP addresses of the individual app containers.

```sh
$ docker compose up -d
$ docker run --network sample --rm tutum/dnsutils dig +short app
172.22.0.3
172.22.0.2
```

You can actually tell load balancers like nginx or HAProxy to use the docker resolver for service discovery.

This doesn't tell you what capabilities the app containers have, but I think it also doesn't really matter. Unless I misunderstand your question and there is more to it.

Compose already adds these replicas under the same [alias](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/#create-a-network-alias-for-a-container) to the network. That's also why I could just query for `app` although the container names are actually `project_app_1` and `project_app_2`.

```sh
$ docker run --network sample --rm tutum/dnsutils dig +short sample_app_1
172.22.0.3
```

So, you are essentially getting DNS round-robin as the built-in solution offered by compose.

You can even take this a step further, if you want to load balancer across separate services as one entity. Say type x or type y.

```yaml
services:
  app:
    image: nginx
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - nginx

  other:
    image: nginx
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - nginx

networks:
  default:
    name: sample
```

```sh
docker run --network sample --rm tutum/dnsutils dig +short nginx
172.22.0.2
172.22.0.4
172.22.0.5
172.22.0.3
```

You could pair this as described above with a loadbalancer. I.E. haproxy.

For example, you could have a config file like this.

```
resolvers docker
    nameserver dns1 127.0.0.11:53
    resolve_retries 3
    timeout resolve 1s
    timeout retry   1s
    hold other      10s
    hold refused    10s
    hold nx         10s
    hold timeout    10s
    hold valid      10s
    hold obsolete   10s

global
    log          fd@2 local2
    stats timeout 2m
    spread-checks 15

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option httplog
    timeout connect 5s
    timeout check 5s
    timeout client 2m
    timeout server 2m

listen stats
    bind *:4450
    stats enable
    stats uri /
    stats refresh 15s
    stats show-legends
    stats show-node

frontend default
    bind *:8080
    default_backend nginx

backend nginx
    balance leastconn
    option httpchk GET /
    server-template nginx- 10 nginx:80 resolvers docker init-addr libc,none check inter 30s
```

If you bake this into a HAProxy image or mount the file for simplicity, you get proper load balancer instead of DNS round-robin. You can have different load balancing algorithms and session affinity / persistence.

```yaml
services:
  app:
    &nginx
    image: nginx
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - nginx

  other: *nginx

  lb:
    image: haproxy:2.5-alpine3.15
    ports:
      - 8000:8080
      - 4450:4450
    volumes:
      - ./haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

Now we can see on the stats' page on port 4450 the 4 instances with nginx alias.

[image: haproxy stats]

You can also check out this answer, which contains related information and shows some other strategies next to HAProxy.  [How does service discovery work with modern docker/docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683508/how-does-service-discovery-work-with-modern-docker-docker-compose/64867075#64867075).

This answer showcases aliases with the docker CLI, so you may understand what compose is doing there. [how are compose services implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70870136/how-are-compose-services-implemented/70901286#70901286)

In Kubernetes, you would pretty much get the same things to work with. Kubernetes has also its own DNS resolver and service abstractions to get VIP or DNS round-robin behaviour. The rest has to come from an external implementation, such as an ingress controller.

Comment: Thanks, I have just looked up tutum/dnsutils its absolute gold. My load balancing/routing is specific to the app (database) I am using so I need to work out how it uses names with multiple resolutions, and perhaps write some custom logic there. But essentially "{name}" resolving to all servers that look like "{project}_{name}_{number}" was what I was looking for

Comment: I think Kubernetes is what I need to go for anyway, many things are pointing that way currently

Comment: dnsutils contains basically just nslookup and dig. It's a convenient for small examples or debugging scenarios. But I think it's not maintained any more, though. I go last time,  warning that it's using an older version of the manifest. But you can do a DNS query with a lot of things and from any programming language, I guess.